# How to get all permissions of a specific user in Keycloak as an admin over an API

Tags: permissions, authorization, keycloak

I am trying to get all permissions of a user with an admin account.

If I get an access token for my user and use this endpoint:

```
POST 'https://<HOST>/auth/realms/<REALM>/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```

with this header/body:

```
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_USER>'
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \\
--data-urlencode 'audience=<CLIENT>' \\
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket'
```

I get a new token with all the information I need (including permissions for resources and their scopes).

Now I want to get all these information without knowing the credentials of the user but with those of the admin. In the admin console you get access to all these information as an admin. So I guess, it should be possible to evaluate all permissions of a specific user with just the admin access.
But what request/requests do I have to do?

(I am using Keycloak 17-**Wildfly**)

Comment: did you get any solution for this? I'm still trying to do that

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. I had to change my project to get the credentials of the user for this request...If you find a way, please let me know

Comment: @chathun, I'm in the same situation. Were you able to find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `--data-urlencode 'response_mode=permissions'`, in this case you will get json list with all resources and scopes for user